# echo bash code to .sh file to execute mixed up the variables

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create .sh file with the following code:

```sh
x=1; while [ $x -le 5 ]; do echo "Welcome $x times" $(( x++ )); done
```

now I'm using the echo command to keep this process command implemented as much as possible,
so I'm using this command to do it:

```sh
echo "x=1; while [ $x -le 5 ]; do echo "Welcome $x times" $(( x++ )); done" > main.sh
```

and when I use cat command to see what was written to the file, I get this:

```sh
x=1; while [ 17 -le 5 ]; do echo "Welcome 17 times" 17; done
```

how can I write this code to the file using command as such as this?

Comment: Why don't you use a text editor for creating a program? It's much simpler and less error prone.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with quoting.

Where you're trying to put inner double quotes, you're actually ending the outer double quotes. Additionally, you need the outer quotes to be single quotes to prevent bash from substituting the variables and arithmetic with their values.

```sh
echo 'x=1; while [ $x -le 5 ]; do echo "Welcome $x times" $(( x++ )); done' > main.sh
```